# Can't decode JSON "_TypeError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index')"

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried every solution on StackOverflow but couldn't find any answers.
I'm getting API calls and then trying to decode them to use in my app.
However, I couldn't find a way to do that. It gives me an error every time!

The response I get from API

```
{success: true, error: null, data: {id: zP********P, name: FTBContinuum, address: FTBContinuum.exaroton.me, motd: cidqu sunucusuna ho geldin!, status: 0, host: null, port: null, players: {max: 20, count: 0, list: []}, software: {id: RUg3PF9qeRywv4Z2, name: FTB Continuum, version: 1.7.0}, shared: false}}
```

Here is my code:

```
  girisFonksiyonu() async {
    var krediF = await sunucu.accountInfo('credits');
    var sunucu31 = await sunucu.servers('z*******P');
    print(sunucu31);
    var continuum = jsonEncode(sunucu31);
    var decodedJSON = jsonDecode(continuum);
    var sunucuIDF = decodedJSON['data']['id'];
    var sunucuismiF = decodedJSON['data']['name'];
    var sunucumotdF = decodedJSON['data']['motd'];
    var durumF = decodedJSON['data']['status'].toString();
    var girislikisiF = decodedJSON['data']['players']['count'].toString();
```

servers function:

```
  Future<String> servers(String serverId) async {
    var endpoint = 'servers/$serverId/';
    var notParsedJSON = await postSystem(endpoint);
    var decodedJSON = jsonDecode(notParsedJSON);
    var info = decodedJSON;
    return info.toString();
  }
```

postSystem function:

```
  Future<String> postSystem(String endpoint) async {
    var postUrl = '${env.baseUrl}/${endpoint}';

    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse('${postUrl}'),
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ${API_KEY}',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
    );
    return response.body.toString();
  }
```

Here is the error I got:

[image]

Comment: what do you get when you  `debugPrint(decodedJSON )`

Comment: @DanielSogbey {success: true, error: null, data: {id: zP********FEP, name: FTBContinuum, address: FTBContinuum.exaroton.me, motd: cidqu sunucusuna ho geldin!, status: 0, host: null, port: null, players: {max: 20, count: 0, list: []}, software: {id: RUg3PF9qeRywv4Z2, name: FTB Continuum, version: 1.7.0}, shared: false}}

Comment: Please paste the error as text here and not as image. That will be easier to relate to

Comment: @Sisir It is already on the title. I posted as an image to show where the error happened.

Comment: @CidQu does jsonDecode['success'] result in true

Answer (score 0):

your code seeing the decoededJSON as a List so the data here should be int index if you are using a list if you not then you need to decode your JSON in other way to get correct data type you can provide us with json data to help you more

Comment: JSON data is already in post. But I can share it here as well. {success: true, error: null, data: {id: zP********FEP, name: FTBContinuum, address: FTBContinuum.exaroton.me, motd: cidqu sunucusuna ho geldin!, status: 0, host: null, port: null, players: {max: 20, count: 0, list: []}, software: {id: RUg3PF9qeRywv4Z2, name: FTB Continuum, version: 1.7.0}, shared: false}}

Answer (score 0):

decodeJson can return a list from json Array or a map,
if its return a list the index must be int

if return a map the index can be string

so instead of using var, try to set a return type :

```
Map<String,dynamic> decodedJSON = jsonDecode(continuum);
var sunucuIDF = decodedJSON['data']['id'];
```

Comment: Now I get:

Exception has occurred.
_TypeError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>')

Comment: i try your code, its print (zP********FEP). successfully, which line you get that error from?

Comment: my sugesstion is make a class for modelling your json. so you can set what type of each parameters.  var sunucu IDF should be String sunucuIDF, if the data is bool, return bool, etc. you just get type error there

Comment: check flutter documentation here : https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/json